# Get Max Priority Fee (miner tip) from transactions in transaction pool (mempool)

Tags: go-ethereum, fees, txpool

I'm scanning the transaction pool via [txpool_content](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-txpool). However, for each pending / queued transaction, I only see they keys 'gas' and 'gasPrice'. How does one check what the maxPriorityFee is for each transaction? I saw in the go-ethereum github the transaction object is supposed to have a [GasTipCap](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/be9742721f56eb8bb7ebf4f6a03fb01b13a05408/core/types/transaction.go#L271)?

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, not every transaction is type-2(EIP 1559) yet. So it might be the reason you do not see any.

The EIP 1559 is backward compatible, meaning that old legacy transactions still go through!